# Custom class iterator following a list of integer indices?

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, iterator

I've got a templated class `myClass` that owns an instance of `std::vector`, and I've overloaded the `[]` operator to take as argument a `std::vector<int>` of indices on the member vector and return a secondary class `mySubset`

```
template <typename _type> 
class myClass {
    // ...
    std::vector<_type> data;
    // ...
    class mySubset {
        myClass<_type>* mc; 
        const std::vector<int>::iterator &idx; 
    public:
        //constructor
        mySubset(myClass<_type> * _m, const std::vector<int>& _idx);
        // input operator overloads (for data and range input)
        template <typename _input_type> mySubset& operator=(const std::vector<_input_type>& _vals);
        mySubset& operator=(const mySubset& _sbst);
    };

public:

    myClass();
    ~myClass(); 
    // ...
    //acess operator
    mySubset operator[](const std::vector<int>& _idx) { return mySubset(_idx); };
    // ...
    //iterator
    typename std::vector<_type>::iterator begin() {return data.begin();};
    typename std::vector<_type>::iterator end();  {return data.end();  };
    // ...
}
```

I'm able to get and set values directly with the `[]` operator, but I'd like to be able to use range-based loops, e.g.

```
// ...
myClass<float> foo;
// ...
std::vector<int> indices (3);
indices[0] = 3;
indices[1] = 6;
indices[2] = 10;
// ...
foo[indices] = std::vector<float> (3, 0.47);

for (auto& fval : foo[indices]) { /* do stuff*/}
```

From what I've gathered, I'd need the `advance( InputIt& it, Distance n );` to achieve what I want, and add `begin()` and `end()` members to `mySubset` that return an iterator-like type object with the `++` operator incrementing the iterator by looking at the index vector:

```
class myIterator {
    mySubset * sb;
    std::vector<_type> it; // myClass::data iterator
public:
    myIterator(mySubset * _sb, int pos): sb(_sb) { it = sb->mc->data.begin() + sb->idx[0]; }   ;
    myIterator& operator++() { };
    myIterator& operator!=(myIterator& _other) { };
};

//.. mySubset
myIterator begin();
myIterator end();
```

But at the moment I'm having trouble understanding what is the actual syntax required to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be lazy.

Go and implement `_type& operator[](size_t)` and `.size()` on `mySubset`.

```
template<class C>
struct range_for_helper{
  using self=range_for_helper;
  C* c=0;
  std::size_t i = 0;
  self(C* cin, std::size_t idx):c(cin),i(idx){}
  friend bool operator==(self lhs, self rhs){return lhs.i==rhs.i;}
  friend bool operator!=(self lhs, self rhs){return lhs.i!=rhs.i;}
  void operator++(){++i;}
  decltype(auto) operator*(){ return (*c)[i]; }
};
```

Then add

to `mySubset` and done.

It isn't a real iterator, but sufficient for `for(:)` loops.  It could be extended to a real iterator, bit like I said, lazy.

Also :

```
range_for_helper<mySubset> begin() const { return {this,0}; }
range_for_helper<mySubset> end() const { return {this,size()}; }
```

just works if your `[]` is overloaded for `const`, so that is nice.

Comment: Fair enough, seems like a simple enough solution. However, how exactly is `_type& operator[](size_t)` supposed to return a data value from the index vector size?

Comment: @joaocandre First, `const std::vector<int>::iterator & idx` get rid of `const&` there.  There is no way that is defined behavior in any practical use; you pass a vector into the ctor, probably call begin, that begin iterator expires when the ctor is done.  Second, you can obviously get the nth item, that is what your `operator=` has to do.  Third, `(mc-> data)[idx[i]]`.

Comment: "that begin iterator expires when the ctor is done" well, it makes sense and I was unaware of that. Also, I was looking at `i` as the fixed size of the index vector instead of the *current* index.